# Parametrized global filter on C# .NET 6.0 with ILogger argument (DI)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, instance

I'm trying to declare a parametrized global filter in my program.cs in the following way:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
        // Green line warning given in this line below ----------------
    var logger = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ILogger<ResponseHeaderActionFilter>>();

    options.Filters.Add(new ResponseHeaderActionFilter(logger, "X-Global-State", "Started"));
});
```

However, I'm getting this warning:

> "Calling BuildServiceProvider from application code results in additional copy of Singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as DI services  as parameters to configure."

Which makes sense, the only problem is that I'm using serilog `ILogger<T>` in the *constructor* of my `ResponseHeaderActionFilter` class.

- What is the best way to pass a DI when creating a new instance of a class to avoid the duplication of services?

Below the class `ResponseHeaderActionFilter` for reference:

```
namespace ContactsManager.Filters.ActionFilters
{
    public class ResponseHeaderActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ResponseHeaderActionFilter> _logger;
        private readonly string _key;
        private readonly string _value;
        public ResponseHeaderActionFilter(ILogger<ResponseHeaderActionFilter> logger, string key, string value)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _key = key;
            _value = value;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{FilterName}.{MethodName} executed", nameof(ResponseHeaderActionFilter), nameof(OnActionExecuted));

            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers[_key] = _value;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{FilterName}.{MethodName} executed", nameof(ResponseHeaderActionFilter), nameof(OnActionExecuting));
        }
    }
}
```

The code above was tried

Answer (score 0):

One of workarounds is to change the way you add your filter to

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews( options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<ResponseHeaderActionFilter>();
} );
```

This lets you inject whatever you want to your filter, not only an `ILogger` but also even the `IServiceProvider` itself.

```
public class ResponseHeaderActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public ResponseHeaderActionFilter( 
        IServiceProvider sp, 
        ILogger<ResponseHeaderActionFilter> logger )
    {
        // get anything from the sp
        var _service = sp.GetRequiredService<IWhatever>();
      
        // logger is also injected
    }
```

The only drawback of this approach is that you can't inject string arguments so you either have these fixed or have an abstract filter class that doesn't provide any specific string values and a child filter class that just provides these string values.